# Link Firebase for each build types

Tags: android, firebase

I have 3 mode of build types- debug, stage, release.
FCM, Firebase analytics had been integrated on my app.
My goal is to link different Firebase projects in each mode of my build.
As an example, if I build my app in stage mode, then Firebase project project_stage should be linked to my app, so all firebase settings should be worked with project_stage.
If I do some action, then analytics will be logged to project_stage, and I would need to get notification from project_stage.
Same for project_live and project_debug.
I have tried several ways but didn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the desired name as `buildConfigField` `FIREBASE_APP_NAME` or `R.string.firebase_app_name`:

```
android {
    // default configuration, don't touch.
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "FIREBASE_APP_NAME", "\"default\""
        resValue("string", "firebase_app_name", "default")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        staging {}
        release {}
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {} // default source-set
        foo {}
        bar {}
    }
    productFlavors {
        foo {
            buildConfigField "String", "FIREBASE_APP_NAME", "\"foo\""
            resValue("string", "firebase_app_name", "foo")
        }
        bar {
            buildConfigField "String", "FIREBASE_APP_NAME", "\"bar\""
            resValue("string", "firebase_app_name", "bar")
        }
    }
}
```

One can likely either configure `productFlavors` or `buildTypes`, unless combining app names. However, then one can instance [`FirebaseApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) with the name inside the application package:

```
FirebaseApp.getInstance(BuildConfig.FIREBASE_APP_NAME);
```

Or with `string` resource:

```
FirebaseApp.getInstance(getString(R.string.firebase_app_name));
```

There's also an [`android.environments`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/android.environments) Gradle plugin for generating these `buildConfigField`.

---

Likewise, one could just use a `string` resource in the proper `res` directory. When configuring `productFlavors` and `sourceSets` with the same names (and obviously also the corresponding directories & files), one can configure all the rest with `string` resources, instead of Android DSL.

Gradle [`sourceSets`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) permit for more than just alternate `string` resources ...